# relay_domains seems to be ignored by postfix

Tags: postfix, smtp

I am trying to set up a perimeter spam and malware filter using CentOS/Postfix/SpamAssassin. Unfortunately, I am still stuck on the PostFix part. I've setup a new subdomain DNS with its own A/MX record (the MX points to the A), and that's working fine. I've also setup a basic PostFix conf using Webmin and editing the main.cf file according to http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html, with an entry for `relay_domains = mailtest.mydomain.com`. I send an email to `user@mailtest.mydomain.com` expecting it to recognize `mailtest.mydomain.com` as a relay domain, and at *least* get to the point of trying to figure out how to relay it (maybe there would be a failure in terms of looking up whether it is allowed to be relayed, where it's relayed to, the receiving host barfs, etc.) However, it never gets that far, and in my `maillog` I see:

```
Apr  5 16:06:59 localhost postfix/smtpd[13518]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mailout-       
us.gmx.com[74.208.5.67]: 550 5.1.1 <jshin@mailtest.#####.com>: Recipient address
rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; from=<randymoses@gmx.com> to
<jshin@mailtest.#####.com> proto=SMTP helo=<mailout-us.gmx.com>
```

...so I can conclude it's still trying to deliver locally.

Now, I have not disabled local delivery, mainly because I do not know how to do so. I would think however that it would at least *try* to relay it and match it against a domain.

One line in the main conf file that troubling to me was the following

```
# NOTE: Postfix will not automatically forward mail for domains that
# list this system as their primary or backup MX host. See the
# permit_mx_backup restriction description in postconf(5).
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not "not getting that far", it's getting past there by recognizing it as a local hostname, which obviously doesn't need to be relayed.  You do not want the mailer to consider the relay domain local; you want it to have its own local hostname, with the MX pointing to it (i.e. not MX and A being the same; that's actually quite meaningless as it implies relaying to itself).

Comment: Forgive me if this is thick, but what do you suggest I do to resolve the problem? The local hostname of my CentOS vm != dns name... I just it to sit "in front of" my Exchange server and forward all mail for `relay_domains` to it at this point.

Comment: Nevermind... you were right! My host name was NOT the same as the DNS name, BUT I had specified the relay domain as an accepted domain for local delivery, effectively the same effect...